# How to remove an object from an array of objects in java

Tags: java, arrays

I need to make a method which deletes all objects in an array of objects that have the variable grade=1 and return the "resized" array of objects.

the objects looks like this:

```
public class Exam {
   private Course course; // Course is a class
   private Student student; // Student is a class
   private Integer grade;
   private LocalDateTime date; }

public class Student{
    private String id;
    private LocalDate birthDate; }

public class Course {
   private String id;
   private String name;
   private Integer ECTS;
   private Profesor subjectBearer;
   private Student[] student;}
```

the method needs to look something like this:

```
private Exam[] filterPassedExams(Exam[] exams) { ...}
```

any help or advice on how to solve the problem without using the lists would be awesome [on the course we didn't learn list yet so we can't really use them
(But I would like to know that solution also if its faster for the future usage)].

Comment: Have you thought about a solution? Tried something? What's the concrete problem you're facing? Note that the signature of your method contradicts the title and the text of your question: the method creates another array, containing only the passed exams. it doesn't remove anything from the original array. That should guide you to the solution.

Comment: This problem has been answered and implemented many, many times. Assuming you have done some minimal research it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @JBNizet i would make a loop that itterats through field to find  the exam[i].getGrade that =1 but i dont know how to "delete that whole object " to resize the field. I would like to copy the  objects 1 by 1 but i dont have the dynamic field so im stuck .

Comment: Again, you shouldn't delete or resize anything. You should create another array, of the right length, and copy all the exams with the accepted grade to that new array.

Comment: so i should first itterate through the field and count how many grades are >1. then crate new array of that size and then itterate again through field and if grade>1 copy it?

Comment: @SinorBodl exactly. You got it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd stream the array, filter the exams you need to retain, and convert the stream back to an array:

```
private Exam[] filterPassedExams(Exam[] exams) {
    return Arrays.stream(exams).filter(e -> e.grade.intValue() != 1).toArray(Exam[]::new);
}
```

Comment: This solution is too complicated for a beginner.

Comment: I'd do that too, but if Lists are forbidden because they haven't been learnt yet, I doubt Streams have.

Comment: To use `Stream`at least Java 8 is needed. But then unboxing will be applied too: no need for `.intValue()`

Comment: OP is probably using Java 8, since `LocalDate` is used.

Comment: @MCEmperor It's just a hint that if the answer uses Java 8, then it could also let  the compiler do the `int` unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to iterate over `exams` and at once collect the passed exams in a new array `passedExams`:

```
  private Exam[] filterPassedExams(Exam[] exams) {
    Exam[] passedExams = new Exam[exams.length];
    int size = 0;
    for (Exam exam : exams) {
      if (exam.getGrade() != 1) {
        passedExams[size++] = exam;
      }
    }

    return size == exams.length ?
      exams :
      Arrays.copyOf(passedExams, size);
  }
```

Since all exams might be passed the new array `passedExams` is initialized with the length of `exams`. If all exams has been passed, we return the original array. Otherwise we resize the `passedExams` array using `Arrays.copyOf`which returns a new array with the counted `size`.

Since an array has a fixed size, it's not possible to delete elements. Elements can be set `null` but not deleted. Thus it's impossible to resize an array. A new array with the filtered elements has to be created.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Exam[] filterPassedExams(Exam[] exams) {    
    int size = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<exams.length;i++){
        if(exams[i].getGrade() != 1)
            size++;
    }
    Exam[] tmp = new Exam[size];
    size=0;
    for(int i=0;i<exams.length;i++){
        if(exams[i].getGrade() != 1)
            tmp[size++] = exams[i];
    }   

    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: how to solve the problem **withouth using the lists**.

Answer (score 0):

Java is always pass-by-value. Your `exams` array is a copy of the argument you sent.
Anyhow, as you are not supposed to use list you can run a loop and check for grades that are not 1, keep a counter. Then create a new array with the size of the counter. Filter the `exams` array again and this time assign the passed objects to newly created array. return the filtered array.

```
private Exam[] filterPassedExams(Exam[] exams) {
    int size = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<exams.length; i++)
         if(exam[i].getGrades !=1)
           size++;

    Exam[] filteredExams = new Exam[size]; //create a new array

    size = -1; //lets reuse this

    for(int i=0; i<exams.length; i++)
         if(exam[i].getGrades !=1)
           filteredExams[++size] = exam[i]; // assign the passed exam object to new filtered exam array

    return filteredExams;
}
```